# Send contents of clipboard as keystrokes in AutoHotkey

Tags: automation, clipboard, autohotkey

I'm looking for a way to send the contents of the clípboard as key output. E.g. if the clipboard says "123456789" I want the keys 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9 sent to the keyboard input.

I've tried:

```
SetWinDelay 100
SetKeyDelay 0

^f::
Send %clipboard%
return
```

To map the 'clipboard paste' to ctrl+f, but it is just literally pasting '%clipboard%'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SendRaw %clipboard%
```

Did the trick

Comment: Perfect for "pasting" those pesky long paths or product keys to VMs!

Comment: @abcde123483 nice but new lines turn into double new line.
is there any way to prevent this?